# How can i display time in place of button?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to **display a time in place of button** when button clicked then
button fadein and time show in place of button but my script not
working button fadein only and time didn't show in place of button and
"Time shown when i refresh the whole page but not a particular part
refreshing."

```
foreach($leads as $val):?>
<tr><td class = 'account-name sort-value'>
<span style='float:left;width:47%;'>
<?php echo $val->first_name .' '. $val->last_name;?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php
if($val->checkin_time != '') {?>
<span class = 'Dischktime' id = 'dischktime{<?php echo $val->lead_id;?>}' ><?php echo $val->checkin_time;?>
</span>
<?php 
}
else {?>
<span style='float:left;width:26%;'>
<button id ='checkin{<?php echo $val->lead_id;?>}' class='btn btn-default' name='checkinbt' value='<?php echo$val->lead_id; type='button'>CheckIn
</button>
</span>
<?php }
?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span>
<?php echo $_SESSION['drivername'];?>
</span>
</td></tr>
<?php endforeach;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[id=checkin]").on("click" , function() {
//$(this).fadeOut();
$(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
//alert("it's working");
$("‪#‎dischktime‬").show();-------(Not working)
});
$('button').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
//alert($(this).attr('value'));
var lead_id = $(this).attr('value');
//alert(lead_id);
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: 'search_db_test.php',
data: 'checkinbt=' + lead_id,
success: function(data) {
$(this).html(data);
//$("#dischktime").show(data);-----(Not working)
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Css Property

`$("#dischktime‬").css('display', 'block') instead of $("‪#‎dischktime‬").show();`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating element based on condition. When button is shown your Time span having id : dischktime is not created and thus its not available in DOM. Modify you foreach :

```
    foreach($leads as $val):?>
    <tr><td class = 'account-name sort-value'>
    <span style='float:left;width:47%;'>
    <?php echo $val->first_name .' '. $val->last_name;?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php
    if($val->checkin_time != '') {?>
    <span class = 'Dischktime' id = 'dischktime{<?php echo $val->lead_id;?>}' ><?php echo $val->checkin_time;?>
    </span>
    <?php 
    }
    else {?>
    <span style='float:left;width:26%;'>
    <button id ='checkin{<?php echo $val->lead_id;?>}' class='btn btn-default' name='checkinbt' value='<?php echo$val->lead_id; type='button'>CheckIn
    </button>
    </span>
**<span style="display:none;" class = 'Dischktime ' id = 'dischktime{<?php echo $val->lead_id;?>}' >**
    </span>
    <?php }
    ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['drivername'];?>
    </span>
    </td></tr>
    <?php endforeach;
    }
```

Comment: Don't copy paste my code. I just gave as reference. 
The if else that you have for checkin_time.
In that create span of time in both case. In case when button is shown , hide the time span. and as user click on button , hide button and show the time hidden span. Thus this logic go well ?